# How to make memory and cpu efficient a code

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, async-await, python-requests

I am using a python scraper code to grab publicly available data from `http://103.48.16.132/echalan/` but it takes almost ~6gb of memory and more cpu. I need to run multiple instance of the this code which is not possible thusly. Can anyone suggest me a tweak or edit to lessen the memory and cpu footprint of this code. I already added `gc` and deleted unused variable but all in vain.

Workflow of the code roughly:

1. Generate date from a give date range and iterate over each date for
   multiple challan no  for each bank branch to collect data.
2. Save data to a dataframe and finally to csv Save the collected data
   ID and no-data ID to a file with extension `.dat`
3. If resumed then analyse the done and no-data IDs and proceed with
   the not-done IDs.

Code I use-

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import warnings
import re
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)
import requests,sys,os
from datetime import datetime
from itertools import *
import time,gc
import pandas as pd
import lxml.html as LH
from datetime import timedelta, date
import pathlib
from collections.abc import Iterable
import requests,aiohttp,asyncio
start_timeTot = time.time()


bank_brnch = {'2573838': 'Agargaon (SB)', '42238412': 'AGLA, DHAKA', '41829141': 'Agrani Balika Bidyalaya (SB)', '42238417': 'AMIN BAZAR, DHAKA', '42238434': 'ARMANITOLA, DHAKA', '44205532': 'ASHULIA BAZAR', '42238436': 'ATI BAZAR, DHAKA', '42238443': 'AWLAD HOSSAIN MARKET, DHAKA', '1217867': 'B.B. Avenue Corp,Dhaka (SB)', '42238447': 'B.I.S.E., DHAKA', '42238448': 'B.M.E. BOARD, DHAKA', '42238451': 'B.U.E.T., DHAKA', '42238452': 'BABUBAZAR, DHAKA', '1218486': 'Badda, Dhaka (SB)', '1218487': 'Baitul Mokarrom,Dhaka (SB)', '42238453': 'BAJME KADERIA COMPLEX, DHAKA', '42238455': 'BANANI BAZAR, DHAKA', '1218488': 'Banani, Dhaka (SB)', '42238461': 'BANGA BANDHU JATIO STADIUM, DHAKA', '42238466': 'BANGA BHABAN, DHAKA', '2549487': 'Baridhara (SB)', '42238480': 'BASABO, DHAKA', '42238486': 'BAWANINAGAR, DHAKA', '1218708': 'Begum Rokeya Sarani,Dhaka (SB)', '1218720': 'Chawk Bazar,Dhaka', '42238489': 'CHURAIN, DHAKA', '41458064': 'COLLEGE GATE (SB)', '1218496': 'Custom House, Dhaka', '1218721': 'D.C.Hall, Dhaka', '1218715': 'D.E.P.Z,Dhaka', '1218489': 'Dhaka Cantt., Dhaka (SB)', '1218497': 'Dhaka Registration Com.,Dhaka', '41614746': 'DHAKA UNIVERSITY CAMPUS (SB)', '115': 'Dhamrai (SB)', '3649899': 'Dhanmondi Corp. (SB)', '1218502': 'Dilkusha Corp.Br., Dhaka (SB)', '42238494': 'DISTILARY ROAD, DHAKA', '1218500': 'Doyagonj, Dhaka', '1218503': 'Fakirapool,Dhaka (SB)', '1857462': 'Farash gonj, Dhaka (SB)', '1218490': 'Farmgate, Dhaka (SB)', '42238498': 'FOREIGN EXCHANGE CORPORATE, DHAKA', '42238501': 'GANA BHABAN, DHAKA', '42238505': 'GORAN, DHAKA', '42238507': 'GREEN ROAD, DHAKA', '42070627': 'GULSHAN (SB)', '1218491': 'Gulshan New North,Dhaka (SB)', '42238511': 'HAZARIBAG, DHAKA', '41293811': 'HAZRAT SHAHJALAL INTL AIRPORT', '42238512': 'Hotel Inter-Continental Br(SHERATAN),DHAKA', '42238517': 'IBRAHIMPUR, DHAKA', '42238524': 'ISHWARCHANDRA STREET, DHAKA', '36250033': 'JATIO SANGSAD BHABAN BR.', '1218651': 'Jatrabari, Dhaka (SB)', '417': 'Joypara (SB)', '1218696': 'Kakrail,Dhaka (SB)', '42238528': 'KALAKOPA, DHAKA', '42238533': 'KALAMPUR, DHAKA', '42238536': 'KALATIA, DHAKA', '41839603': 'KALYAN PUR (SB)', '5602261': 'Kamlapur Rly. St. ICD Br.', '42238538': 'KAWRAN BAZAR, DHAKA,SB', '418': 'Keraniganj (SB)', '1218654': 'Khilgaon, Dhaka (SB)', '42143382': 'KRISHI BAZAR MOHAMMADPUR', '41751373': 'KRISHI BHABAN (SB)', '42238541': 'KURMITOLA, DHAKA', '1218723': 'Lalbagh,Dhaka (SB)', '1218698': 'Lalmatia,Dhaka (SB)', '1857477': 'Laxmi Bazar, Dhaka (SB)', '1217860': 'Local Office,Dhaka', '42238544': 'MAKIM KATRA, DHAKA', '1218656': 'Malibagh,Dhaka (SB)', '42241715': 'MANIK MIAH AVENUE, DHAKA', '1218700': 'Md.Pur Bazar, Dhaka (SB)', '42238546': 'MIRPUR CANTT., DHAKA', '1218711': 'Mirpur I/A, Dhaka', '2717246': 'Mirpur Sec-1', '42238547': 'MITFORD ROAD, DHAKA', '1218493': 'Mogh Bazar, Dhaka (SB)', '1218494': 'Mohakhali, Dhaka (SB)', '1218498': 'N.C.T.B,Dhaka (SB)', '2549438': 'Nagar Bhabon (SB)', '42238548': 'NAJIRABAZAR, DHAKA', '41829146': 'Naval H/Q (SB)', '419': 'Nawabganj (Dhaka)', '1218724': 'Nawabpur Road,Dhaka', '42238563': 'NAYABAZAR, DHAKA', '42238570': 'NAYARHAT, DHAKA', '1218762': 'Nazimuddin Road, Dhaka (SB)', '1218665': 'New Market, Dhaka', '2452744': 'North South Road Br. Dhaka (SB)', '42238573': 'P.A.T.C. (SAVAR), DHAKA', '42238574': 'PALAMGANJ, DHAKA', '1218699': 'Pallabi Br. (Mirpur-12 ), Dhaka', '44332559': 'PANGAON ICT BR.', '1218725': 'Postagola,Dhaka (SB)', '41581585': "PRIME MINISTER'S OFFICE (SB)", '40338614': 'Public Service Commission Branch (Dhaka Airport Branch)', '42238578': 'RAJUK BHABAN, DHAKA', '4039439': 'Ramna Corporate Branch (SB)', '42238581': 'RAMPURA, DHAKA', '42238583': 'RASULPUR BAZAR, DHAKA', '42238588': 'RUHITPUR, DHAKA', '1218726': 'Sadarghat Corp. Br,Dhaka (SB)', '42238593': 'SAIDABAD BUS TERMINAL, DHAKA', '1218701': 'Sat Masjid, Dhaka (SB)', '325': 'Savar (SB)', '1218702': 'Savar Cantt.,Dhaka (SB)', '41423293': 'SEGUN BAGICHA (SB)', '41501647': 'Shahjanpur (SB)', '1218659': 'Shilpa Bhaban,Dhaka (SB)', '1218704': 'Sonargaon Road,Dhaka (SB)', '42139442': 'Sonargoan Hotel (SB)', '1218706': 'Supreme Court,Dhaka (SB)', '42238602': 'TEJGAON INDUSTIAL AREA, DHAKA', '42238606': 'URDU ROAD, DHAKA', '41583041': 'UTTAR KHAN', '41582663': 'UTTARA MODEL TOWN (SB)', '41426798': 'VIQUARUN NESA NOON SCHOOL (SB)', '41660316': 'Wage Earners Corporate (SB)', '2452798': 'WAPDA Building Br.', '1218750': 'Wari, Dhaka (SB)', '1218695': 'Zigatola,Dhaka (SB)'}

ouputpath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]),'C_{0}'.format(time.strftime("%Y%d%m")))#
merge_folder_csv_after_run = False
batch_size_for_async_request = 1000
time_out_for_request_wait = 300
process_missed_accounts_flag = True
headerWriteFlag = True         
donelist = missedlist = noaclist= whataclist = dfschallan = []
start_sd_index = 0
#end_sd_index = len(accounts)
accountErrorFlag = []
switch_code_if_not_found = 20000
total_no_acc_to_change = []
switch_code_if_not_found_in_total = 50000
filepath = ""

def wait_for_internet_connection():
    while True:
        try:
            response = requests.get('https://www.google.com/?hl=bn',timeout=5)
            if response.ok:
                return
        except Exception:
            time.sleep(5)
            print("Waited for internet to connect {}.".format(datetime.now()))
            pass
wait_for_internet_connection()

try:
    with open('missedCHALLAN.dat','r') as f:
        missedlist = f.readlines()
        missedlist = list(filter(None,list(set(list(map(str.strip,missedlist))))))
except:
    pass


try:
    with open('noacCHALLAN.dat','r') as f:
        noaclist = f.readlines()
        noaclist = list(filter(None,list(set(list(map(str.strip,noaclist))))))
except:
    pass

try:
    with open('whatacCHALLAN.dat','r') as f:
        whataclist = f.readlines()
        whataclist = list(filter(None,list(set(list(map(str.strip,whataclist))))))
except:
    pass


try:
    with open('doneCHALLAN.dat','r') as f:
        donelist = f.readlines()
        donelist = list(filter(None,list(map(str.strip,donelist))))
        #donelistSet = set(done_list)# for faster performance convert to set
    #TINSUnique = [tn__ for tn__ in uTINS if tn__ not in donelistSet]
    #TINS = TINSUnique

except:
    pass
#prevent duplicate header write
if len(donelist)>0:
    headerWriteFlag = False

def daterange(date1, date2):
    for n in range(int ((date2 - date1).days)+1):
        yield date1 + timedelta(n)

def _strftime(date):
    return date.strftime(DATE_FORMAT)

def flatten(xs):
    for x in xs:
        if isinstance(x, Iterable) and not isinstance(x, (str, bytes)):
            yield from flatten(x)
        else:
            yield x
            
def _date_range_parameters(start, end, span_days):
    start = _strptime(start)
    end   = _strptime(end)
    span  = timedelta(days=span_days)
    return start, end, span

#File and folder name sanitizer
def sanitize_file_folder_name(ffname):
    reserved_chars = [':','>','<','"','/','\\','*','?','|']
    for rc in reserved_chars:
        ffname = ffname.replace(rc,'_').strip()
    return ffname

def forward_date_range(start, end, span_days):
    """
    Generate tuples with intervals from given range of dates (forward).

    forward_date_range('2012-01-01', '2012-01-5', 2)

    1st yield = ('2012-01-01', '2012-01-03')
    2nd yield = ('2012-01-04', '2012-01-05')
    """
    start, end, span = _date_range_parameters(start, end, span_days)
    stop = end - span

    while start < stop:
        current = start + span
        yield _strftime(start), _strftime(current)
        start = current + DATE_STEP

    yield _strftime(start), _strftime(end)
    s
def chunks(lst, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from lst."""
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]    
def dedeuper(seq):
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    return [x for x in seq if not (x in seen or seen_add(x))]   

async def fetch(acc_,url_,payld_,timout,hdr,check_test_lst,no_acc_check_lst):
    dt = []
    try:
        #connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=10,force_close=True)
        #challanno = payld_['chalan_no']
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            unqID = acc_+"_"+str(payld_['chalan_no'])
            async with session.post(url_,headers=hdr,data = payld_,timeout=timout) as response:
                resp = await response.read()
                #resp = await response.text()
                root = LH.fromstring(resp)
                txt = root.text_content()
                tds = root.xpath("//td")
                #print(root.text_content())
                #AccountName = root.xpath("((//div[contains(@class,'col-lg-9 col-md-9')]//table)[3]//div)[1]")[0].text.strip()
                if all([i not in txt for i in check_test_lst]):
                    #print(txt)
                    dt_dict = [{'UniqueID':acc_,
                    'challan_no':tds[2].text_content().split(":")[-1].strip(),
                    'date' : tds[3].text_content().split(":")[-1].strip(),
                    'bank':tds[5].text_content().split(":")[-1].strip(),
                    'branch' : tds[6].text_content().split(":")[-1].strip(),
                    'code' : tds[7].text_content().split(":")[-1].strip(),
                    'name' : tds[17].text_content().split(":")[-1].strip(),
                    'Amount' : tds[19].text_content().split(":")[-1].strip(),
                    'Timestamp':str(datetime.now())}]

                    dfName1 = pd.DataFrame(dt_dict)
                    dt = [dfName1,acc_]
                    print("Successfully got account {} with response of length {}.".format(unqID, len(resp)))
                    
                elif all([i in txt for i in no_acc_check_lst]):
                    dt = ['NoAC',acc_]
                    print("No account found for {}.".format(unqID))                     
                    
    except Exception as e:
        #pass
        print("Unable to get account {} due to {}.".format(unqID, e.__class__))
        dt = ['Error',acc_]
        print("Error while trying to collect for {}.".format(unqID))
    return dt

    
async def get(_brcd,_postQry,_dat):
    #print('Working on {}'.format(_dat))
    LOGIN_URL = 'http://103.48.16.132/echalan/VerifyChalan_new.php' #'https://CHALLAN.org.bd/service/ebill'
    dt_get = []
    dtframes = []
    challan_miss_counter = []
    time_out_for_request_wait = 3
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        'Origin': 'http://103.48.16.132',
        'Referer': 'http://103.48.16.132/echalan/echalan_iframe.php',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
        'X-Prototype-Version': '1.6.1',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    }    
    challan_nos = list(range(1,99999999))
    breakwhile = False
    while True:
        #global dt_get
        for challan_no in challan_nos:
            payload = {
                'bank_branch_id': _brcd,
                'chalan_date': _dat,
                'chalan_no': challan_no,
                'trans_type' : _postQry,
                'counter_no': '0',
                'bank_id' : '2',
                '_' : ''
            }
            uniqIDforDATE = _brcd+"_"+_postQry+"_"+_dat
            #pass the weekends
            #if parser.parse(_dat).weekday() in [4,5]:
                #continue            
            dt_get = await fetch(uniqIDforDATE,LOGIN_URL,payload,time_out_for_request_wait,headers,['Chalan not found'],['Chalan not found'])
            #time.sleep(random.uniform(0.2,0.8))
            if 'NoAC'  in dt_get[0]:
                challan_miss_counter.append('bypass')
            elif isinstance(dt_get[0],pd.DataFrame):
                dtframes.append(dt_get[0])
    
            if len(challan_miss_counter)>maxCheckToPassSingleDate:
                breakwhile = True
                break
            elif isinstance(dt_get[0],pd.DataFrame):
                challan_miss_counter = []
                
        #safety measure for not data
        if len(dt_get) < 2:
            dt_get = ['What',uniqIDforDATE]
            
        if breakwhile:
            break
    if len(dtframes):
        dfconcated = pd.concat(dtframes)
        dt_get = [dfconcated,uniqIDforDATE]
    return dt_get

async def main(br_code,post_qry_type,date_batch):
    global accountErrorFlag
    global total_no_acc_to_change
    global headerWriteFlag
    #wait for internet connection
    wait_for_internet_connection()
    
    dones,pendings = await asyncio.wait([get(br_code,post_qry_type,dat) for dat in date_batch])
    #print("Finalized all. ret is a list of len {} outputs.".format(len(dones)))
    data_results = [i.result() for i in dones]
    
    dfs = [i[0] for i in data_results if isinstance(i[0],pd.DataFrame)]
    if len(dfs)>0:
        dfNameConcated = pd.concat(dfs)
        dfschallan.append(dfNameConcated)
        name_suffix_done = "_"+sanitize_file_folder_name(bank_brnch[br_code]+"_"+dfNameConcated['UniqueID'].unique().tolist()[0]+"_")
        #Create a folder
        curdir = pathlib.Path().absolute()
        flderpath = curdir.joinpath(sanitize_file_folder_name(bank_brnch[br_code]))
        flderpath.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        nam = '_{0}_{1}'.format(post_qry_type,time.strftime("%d%m%Y"))+name_suffix_done+'.csv'
        filepath = curdir.joinpath(sanitize_file_folder_name(bank_brnch[br_code]))/nam
        
        dfNameConcated.to_csv(filepath,encoding='utf-8-sig',index=False,mode='a',header=headerWriteFlag)
        done_accounts = sorted(dfNameConcated['UniqueID'].unique())
        #write done accounts
        df_done = pd.DataFrame(done_accounts, columns=["done_accounts"])
        done_file_name = 'doneCHALLAN.dat'
        df_done.to_csv(done_file_name, mode = 'a', index=False,header=False)
        headerWriteFlag = False
    
    no_ac_data = [i[0] for i in [i for i in data_results if not isinstance(i[0],pd.DataFrame)] if i[0] == 'NoAC']
    if len(no_ac_data) == batch_size_for_async_request:
        accountErrorFlag = accountErrorFlag+no_ac_data
    elif len(dfs)>0:
        accountErrorFlag=[]
    if len(no_ac_data)>0:
        total_no_acc_to_change = total_no_acc_to_change+no_ac_data
        
    
        
    missed_accounts = [i[1] for i in [i for i in data_results if not isinstance(i[0],pd.DataFrame)] if i[0] == 'Error']
    #write missed accounts
    df_missed = pd.DataFrame(missed_accounts, columns=["missed_accounts"])
    missed_csv_name = 'missedCHALLAN.dat'
    df_missed.to_csv(missed_csv_name,mode = 'a', index=False,header=False)
    
    #process no accounts
    noac_accounts = [i[1] for i in [i for i in data_results if not isinstance(i[0],pd.DataFrame)] if i[0] == 'NoAC']
    #write missed accounts
    df_noac = pd.DataFrame(noac_accounts, columns=["no_accounts"])
    noac_csv_name = 'noacCHALLAN.dat'
    df_noac.to_csv(noac_csv_name,mode = 'a', index=False,header=False)

    #process what accounts
    whatac_accounts = [i[1] for i in [i for i in data_results if not isinstance(i[0],pd.DataFrame)] if i[0] == 'What']
    #write missed accounts
    df_whatac = pd.DataFrame(whatac_accounts, columns=["what_accounts"])
    whatac_csv_name = 'whatacCHALLAN.dat'
    df_whatac.to_csv(whatac_csv_name,mode = 'a', index=False,header=False)
    
    print("Acounts collection perfomance=========================noac/missed/done/what = {0} / {1} / {2} / {3}===========================\
    ".format(len(no_ac_data),len(missed_accounts), len(dfs),len(whatac_accounts)))    
    
    
total_accounts_scraped = 0
xSearchDateList = []
#accounts_ = accounts[start_sd_index:end_sd_index]
accounts_offices = list(bank_brnch.items())
for accounts_office in accounts_offices:
    dtS_ = '2013-01-01' #(Y-M-D) start date
    dtE_ = '2022-06-30' #end date
    dateChunkSixe = 1 #fix 1 for better performance
    maxCheckToPassSingleDate = 500
    batch_size_for_async_request = 1
    
    postQueryTypes = ['C','L']

    
    #argmnts = list(forward_date_range(dtS_, dtE_, dateChunkSixe))
    #argmnts = list(set(argmnts))
    searchable_dates =[]
    
    dtS = time.strptime(dtS_, '%Y-%m-%d')
    dtE = time.strptime(dtE_, '%Y-%m-%d')
    dt_ranges = [date(dtS.tm_year, dtS.tm_mon, dtS.tm_mday),date(dtE.tm_year, dtE.tm_mon, dtE.tm_mday)]
    if isinstance(xSearchDateList,list) and len(xSearchDateList)>0:
        searchable_dates = xSearchDateList
    elif len(dt_ranges)>0 and dt_ranges[0].year != 1900 :
        for dt in daterange(dt_ranges[0], dt_ranges[1]):
            searchable_dates.append(dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
    else:
        raise Exception
    
    searchable_dates_weekdays = searchable_dates #[onday for onday in searchable_dates if parser.parse(onday).weekday() not  in [4,5]]
    total_accounts_scraped=0
    for bank_br in bank_brnch.items():
        for postQueryType in postQueryTypes:
            dfschallan = []
            branchCode = bank_br[0]
            accountsOfficeName = bank_br[-1]
            dones = [donedate.split("_")[-1] for donedate in donelist if branchCode+"_"+postQueryType in donedate]
            noacs = [donedate.split("_")[-1] for donedate in noaclist if branchCode+"_"+postQueryType in donedate]
            D1 = set(dones)
            D2 = set(noacs)
            D = D1.union(D2)
            searchable_dates_not_dones =  [sd for sd in searchable_dates if sd not in D]+missedlist
            
            date_batches = [chunk for chunk in chunks(searchable_dates_not_dones,batch_size_for_async_request)]#[:1]
            del D1,D2,noacs,dones,searchable_dates_not_dones
            for batch in date_batches:
                start_time = time.time()
                asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main(branchCode,postQueryType,batch))
                end_time = time.time()
                total_accounts_scraped += len(batch)
                print("Took {} seconds to pull {} accounts.....................................................\
                ".format(end_time - start_time, total_accounts_scraped))
                gc.collect()
               
            #Write for each branch code for each postQuery Type          
            if merge_folder_csv_after_run:
                date_batches = searchable_dates_weekdays
            elif len(date_batches)<1:
                continue
            
            curdir = pathlib.Path().absolute()
            bank_folder = sanitize_file_folder_name(bank_brnch[branchCode])
            csv_paths = curdir.joinpath(bank_folder)
            flat_list_dates_done = list(flatten(date_batches))
            file_name = sanitize_file_folder_name(bank_folder+"_"+postQueryType+"_"+flat_list_dates_done[0]+"_to_"+flat_list_dates_done[-1])+"_"+'.csv'
            write_path = csv_paths.joinpath(file_name)
            column_headers = ['UniqueID', 'challan_no', 'date', 'bank', 'branch', 'code', 'name', 'Amount', 'Timestamp']            
            
            matched_csvs=[]
            pattern_sample = '{}_{}_{}'.format(bank_folder,branchCode,postQueryType)
            for item in csv_paths.glob(r'**/*'):
                if pattern_sample in str(item):
                    # retrieve the groups of interest
                    matched_csvs.append(str(item))
            if len(matched_csvs)>0:
                dfcsv_br_code = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f,header=None,names=column_headers) for f in list(set(matched_csvs))],axis=0,ignore_index=True)
                dfcsv_br_code_unique = dfcsv_br_code.drop_duplicates(subset=column_headers[1:-1], keep='first')
                #remove any row contains bank
                dfcsv_br_code_unique = dfcsv_br_code_unique[dfcsv_br_code_unique['bank'] != 'bank']
                dfcsv_br_code_unique.to_csv(write_path,encoding='utf-8-sig',index=False,mode='w',header=True)
            
            
            ##Write save df while running
            try:
                flat_list_dates_done = list(flatten(date_batches))
                file_name = sanitize_file_folder_name(bank_brnch[branchCode]+"_"+postQueryType+"_"+flat_list_dates_done[0]+"_to_"+flat_list_dates_done[-1])+"_"+'.csv'
                if len(dfschallan)>0:
                    dfschallanConcated = pd.concat(dfschallan)
                    dfschallanConcated.to_csv(file_name,encoding='utf-8-sig',index=False,mode='w',header=True)
            except:
                pass            

            gc.collect()
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.